# How can EXPECT interpret an escaped character to a command character

Tags: linux, unix, tcl, expect

I'd like to be able to pass in a long command to expect. It's a multiple command somehow. First here's my expect script

---

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
expect "*?username:*"
send "someusername\r"
expect "*?assword:*"
send "somepassword\r"
# Here's the command I'd like to pass from the command prompt
set command [lindex $argv 0]
send "$command\r"
send "exit\r"
```

I would then run this script as so:

```
./expectscript "mkdir /usr/local/dir1\ncd /usr/local/dir1\ntouch testfile"
```

Notice that I put "\n" to initiate an enter as though I'm processing the command before moving to the next.

I know you could separate the commands with ";", but for this particular exercise, I'd like to be able have expect interpret the "\n" with a "\r" so that, expect would behave as though it were like this:

```
send "mkdir /usr/local/dir1\r"
send "cd /usr/local/dir1\r"
send "touch testfile\r"
```

The question then becomes how can expect interpret the "\n" to be "\r"? I've tried putting the "\r" in the argument instead of "\n", but that doesn't work.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do a simple experiment, I find that the `\n` in the argument is not converted by my shell (bash) into a newline; it remains a literal. You can check this out for yourself by just using `puts` to print out the command line argument, like this:

```
puts [lindex $argv 0]
```

Working around this requires a little bit of work to split things. Alas, Tcl's `split` command does *not* split on multi-character sequences (it splits on many different characters at once instead) so we'll need a different approach. However, Tcllib has exactly what we need: the [`splitx`](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/textutil_split.html) command. With that, we do this (based on @tensaix2j's answer):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
package require Expect;            # Good practice to put this explicitly
package require textutil::split;   # Part of Tcllib

# ... add your stuff here ...
foreach line [textutil::split::splitx [lindex $argv 0] {\\n}] {
    send "$line\r"
    # Wait for response and/or prompt?
}
# ... add your stuff here ...
```

If you don't have Tcllib installed and configured for use with Expect, you can also snarf the code for `splitx` directly out of the code (find it online [here](http://tcllib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tcllib/tcllib/modules/textutil/split.tcl?content-type=text%2Fplain)) as long as you internally acknowledge the license it's under (standard Tcl licensing rules).

Comment: Note that it's `{\\n}` for the regexp because we want to match a literal backslash-n and that's the form which minimizes the number of backslashes you have to write to get the literal past both Tcl's parsing and the RE engine's parsing…

Comment: Thanks for taking the extra step to explain your response in detail :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach cmd [ split $command \n ] {
send "$cmd\r\n"
}
```

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to send a `\n` at the end of each of those.